# How to achieve MULTIPLE hyperlink styles within a single div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div that has two simultaneous styles of hyperlink in. A primary one for the more important link, and a secondary one that are relevant to describe the primary one. The point is to have the primary link standout, whereas the secondary ones are un-obtrusive. Now unfortunately it's not applying, and all links appear as the default blue and purple etc.

Apologies if anything is unclear, this is my first time posting here.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="mainContent">
    <a href="https://primary.org" id="primaryLink">The Primary site</a> is a project by the <a href="https://secondary.org" id="secondaryLink">Secondary site/a> that aims to xyz.
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#primaryLink a:link{font-size:20;color:#93186F}
#primaryLink a:visited{font-size:20;color:#77023F}

#secondaryLink a:link{text-decoration:none;color:white;}
#secondaryLink a:visited{text-decoration:none;color:white;}
```

The desired output is something like this:
**The Primary Site** is a project by the *Secondary site* that aims to xyz.

Comment: Typos: "visited", not "visted", and "20px" for the font-size, not just "20". And "</a>"  instead of "/a>" for the closing of the second link. Yes, and the closing `<\/div>`...

Comment: The close div is wrong. It should be </div> not <\/div>

Comment: Granted. The code still doesn't work, however.

Comment: And since the IDs belong to the links themselves, their CSS selectors need to be `a#primaryLink:link`, `a#primaryLink:visited` and similar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have numerous errors in your html and css. Try the following:

```css
#primaryLink {
  font-size: 20;
  color: #93186F;
}

#primaryLink: visited {
  font-size: 20;
  color: #77023F;
}

#secondaryLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#secondaryLink: visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}


/*add background color to see the format you want */

body {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
  <a href="https://primary.org" id="primaryLink">The Primary site</a> is a project by the <a href="https://secondary.org" id="secondaryLink">Secondary site</a> that aims to xyz.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Brent. I appreciate you taking the time to answer, it's seems to have worked.

Comment: Glad to help. If you run into issues like this, you can use validators to check your html and css for errors, that aren't immediately obvious to you. I like to you these: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input for HTML and https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input for the CSS.